# Edit Imported advanced Custom Fields from wordpress Dashboard

Tags: plugins, custom-field, advanced-custom-fields

I have imported advanced custom fields from one of my other site and now I want to add few more options to those fields but I can't figure out how to do it via **Dashboard**? I have imported the field using **php** export/import option of the plugin. Is there anyway that imported fields shows up in Field Groups section in Dashboard?

Comment: Are you referring to your field settings? Or the meta content itself? Is the plugin active? The tab should show up in your dashboard navigation once installed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fields added by PHP are not shown in the Dashboard.

Recently, I came across this post in the *User Submitted Fields* section of ACF forums: [PHP Recovery Tool](http://support.advancedcustomfields.com/discussion/3747/php-recovery-tool).

The author posted a plugin in GitHub, [Advanced Custom Fields Recovery Tool from PHP Export](https://github.com/seamusleahy/ACF-PHP-Recovery). Haven't tested, though.

> Use this plugin to import fieldsets from PHP exports. **Do not use this for your workflow of importing and exporting. Use it only as a recovery tool when you lose the original database and XML files.**

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted! it worked for me.
BTW do you know why he quoted 

"_Use this plugin to import fieldsets from PHP exports. Do not use this for your workflow of importing and exporting. Use it only as a recovery tool when you lose the original database and XML files._"

Comment: Probably he's being over zealous, but maybe the best method is to backup with XML and use the regular WP importer. Nonetheless, nice one to have in the tool-box. Glad it worked ;)

Comment: "Back up with XML and import it using Wp importer" does not populate Custom fields in **Custom fields** area of **dashboard**

Comment: I'm the author of the the PHP Recovery Tool. Regarding the question about the quoted text, I try to make it clear to prevent people from having headaches later on by using it as part of their process because it isn't going to be one-to-one sadly.

The best thing is the keep a copy of the original database with the fields followed by a backup of the fields in the XML format. I'll typically make the changing in a dev database and then export them into PHP for production.